# how do i use original php functions i've created?

Tags: php, function

I think I have everything I need to accomplish what i am trying to do, i just don't know how to combine it all. Could someone please tell me where to put what and how to get it to work? 
Here is what I want and what I have:

I created two functions that I think represent what I am trying to do:

1. a function that accepts 2, 3, or 4 arguments and return both the sum and the average of the arguments supplied.
2. a function that takes any sentence string as an argument. The function reports the length of the string and the number of words in the string. The function replaces the words "cat" and "dog" with "meow" and "bark" IF these words exist in the string. The modified string is returned as an array. If cat and dog aren’t found, the function should return the message string "You have no pets".

I want both of these functions to be used in a second PHP file that uses some function calls for the first function and a Redux to get the string to be examined by the second function. I want to make sure to detect whether the value returned by the second function is an array or a string.

Here is my code:

first function:

```
    <?php
    function sum($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)
    {
    return $var1 + $var2 + $var3 + $var4;
    }

    function mean($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)
    {
    return $var1 + $var2 + $var3 + $var4 / 4;
    }
    ?>
```

Second function:

```
    <?php
    function phptest($input) {
    $search = array('meow', 'bark');
    $replace = array('cat', 'dog');
    $output = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $input, $replace_count);
    if ($replace_count === 0) {
    return false;
    } else {
    return explode(' ', $output);
    }
    }

    $result = phptest($input_string);
    if ($result === false) {
    echo 'You have no pets';
    } else {
    var_dump($result);
    }
    ?>
```

page I have to handle my functions:

```
    <?php
    require('myfunctions.php');
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input name="input" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

thanks so much!

Comment: Not sure what is your problem. Still the average function is not correct. It should return ($var1 + $var2 + $var3 + $var4) / 4.

Comment: Thanks...I'll fix the function. My problem is i just don't know where to put my fucntions in the first folder and how to call them in the second. Does anyone have like a template of how to use functions I could see? Thanks!!

Comment: You probably want to check out the forms handling part of the manual (ond some other sections) http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php - There seems to be no relation between your arithmetic and string processing function. You need to explain better what you are actually trying to do if you want relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your functions to be avalible to multiple files then what you have is correct. Place your PHP functions in the 'myfunctions.php' file, and require it on the pages you want to use them on. you will then be able to call them as you would any other function like so:

```
<?php echo sum(1,2,3,4); ?>
```

To output 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your form doesn't need the php snippet, it needs action which is the script which handles the input, ie

```
<form action="doStuff.php" method="post">
```

and then in the `doStuff.php` file you have something like

```
<?php
require_once('myfunctions.php');
// read the value enterd by the user into variable
$input = $_REQUEST['input'];
// call your function with the value
phptest($input);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to impress your master, create the summation function such that it accepts any number of arguments:

```
    <?php  
    //THE FUNCTION
    function summation() 
    {
        $sum = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i<func_num_args(); $i++) $sum+= func_get_arg($i);
        return $sum;  
    }  
    //THE IMPLEMENTATION
    echo summation(1,5,7); //echo's 13
    echo summation(1,5,6,8) //echo's 20
    ?>
```

Alternatively, you could use PHP's native array_sum function:

```
<?php
$a = array(2, 4, 6, 8);
echo array_sum($a); //echo's 20
?>
```

As for your phptest() function... I suggest naming it something less broad. It's a bad habit to get into sloppy naming conventions; but it looks like it is functional.

You can find the posted information in [PHP's $_POST[] array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp).

Answer (score 0):

after loading the needed php file (preferable with `require_once`, you don't have global code there, do you?) you can access functions the same way you would access functions defined locally.

```
if (isset($_POST['input'])) {
  phptest($_POST['input']);
} else {
  /...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

myfunctions.php:

```
<?php
function sum($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)
{
return $var1 + $var2 + $var3 + $var4;
}

function mean($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4)
{
return $var1 + $var2 + $var3 + $var4 / 4;
}

function phptest($input) {
$search = array('meow', 'bark');
$replace = array('cat', 'dog');
$output = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $input, $replace_count);
if ($replace_count === 0) {
return false;
} else {
return explode(' ', $output);
}
}

?>
```

page u have to handle your functions:

```
<?php
require('myfunctions.php');
if($_POST) {
    $result = phptest($_POST['input']);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo 'You have no pets';
    } else {
        var_dump($result);
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<input name="input" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that...it really helped me. Can anyone see why my function to replace the words stopped working? I've been looking at this code for so long I can't see my own mistakes any more...Thanks!